# Does using a static_cast on a polymorphic object indicate a design flaw?

Tags: c++

I know that dynamic_cast should be avoided, but suppose I have in my program an object x of class Base which I know at a certain point in the execution is also of class Derived (which inherits from Base). Is it acceptable to use static_cast to downcast in order to call Derived methods, etc.? Or does this indicate a design flaw?

Comment: Can you show an example? You typically downcast pointers or references. You don't have objects that are of two types.

Comment: "dynamic_cast should be avoided" is a stupid advice (as every absolute statement like this), there are legitimate use cases.

Comment: Sometimes you have to, but yes, it generally suggests, if not a design *flaw*, at least a suboptimal design

Comment: @MatteoItalia Of course, this kind of advice should always be prefixed with "in general". The advice should really be "In general using `dynamic_cast` indicates a design flaw in your program and one should probably have a very good reason for doing it." I think, however, we should instead be teaching people to not treat this kind of advice as absolute.

Comment: "*Is it acceptable to use static_cast to downcast in order to call Derived methods, etc.?*" Yes, absolutely, as long as you're _positively sure_ that it's actually a `Derived`.

Comment: General rule of thumb. If `A` can be implicitly converted to `B` then `static_cast<>` can be safely used to convert `B` to `A`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It indicates exactly the same design flaw as using `dynamic_cast` would. The fact is, if you're taking a pointer to a base class, it should mean you only use the objects passed as though they were that base class. If you have to determine the dynamic derived type of the object, then you probably shouldn't be taking a pointer to base.

Using a `static_cast` for this is just a little more dangerous than using `dynamic_cast`. You only have well-defined behaviour if the type you're casting to really is correct. With a `dynamic_cast`, at least it tells you if it's not.

As with any advice, there are always exceptions. Just ask yourself if the base pointer type is really appropriate here. We use polymorphism to say "We just want `Fruit`! I don't care if it's an `Apple` or a `Banana` - we'll treat them all the same!" If you're not treating all of your objects like they are the base type, you might like to rethink things. As Mark Ransom gives an example in his answer, sometimes there are cases when you really do want to downcast in this way.

Comment: Thanks. That makes a lot of sense. I'm writing a parallel code in MPI where some processors store more information about certain objects than others (hence, the derived class). But in the parallel code everyone has to execute the same code so I'm passing in the Base class and use an if statement to determine the behavior of my code later. I can see how this is fishy and I will rethink this.

Comment: Another exception is the use of `static_cast` and `final` for optimization purposes.  You have an abstract interface, and sometimes you are going to be calling many virtual functions in it in a row.  By downcasting to a selection of concrete types and then calling `final` `virtual` methods, you can remove `virtual` method call overhead, and even enable eliding the call entirely, while keeping it fully generic and hiding these optimizations from the library user.  I believe [Google Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview) uses this technique.

Answer (score 5):

It has legitimate uses. The [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern (CRTP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) would be impossible without it.

Comment: A good example of when you really do certainly know the derived type of the object (unless it abuses CRTP).

Comment: `static_assert( std::is_base_of< Derived, CRTP_Template_Name<Derived> >, "CRTP used incorrectly" );` makes it really certain.

Answer (score 0):

imo yes, it could indicate a design flaw.  If you know it's a derived class of a certain type,  why is it passed as base class?